# Create database and tables from batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssms

I cant figure out how to execute SQl code by running a batch file.
Ideally I'd be able to double click a batch file and it'd run my SQl code which creates and populates a database and several table.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Heres some simple test code

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB2; 

use testDB2;
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Which platform?

Comment: SQL Server management studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [sqlcmd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) with -Q parameter is what you need.

Comment: Will try this and report back. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Save your code above into a sql file and in a command prompt:

`sqlcmd -S<server>\<instance> -U<user> -P<pass> -i"C:\Path\To\File.sql"`

If you have trusted acces, replace the `-U` and `-P` switches with `-E`

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a better solution!

```
SQLCMD -E -dmaster -ic:\filename.sql
PAUSE
```